# Need simplify sql query with "count" function and "IN" operator

Tags: sql, relational-division

I have a table only consisting of two columns:

```
ObjectID||PropertyID
```

The task: get the all ObjectID whith PropertyID == (P1 and P2 and P3 and ...).

I solved this task:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM  ( 
        SELECT SD.ObjectID ObjectID,
               count( SD.ObjectID )  countMatchingProperties
          FROM table AS SD
         WHERE SD.PropertyID IN ( P1, P2, P3, ..., Pn ) 
         GROUP BY ObjectID 
    ) 
    AS C
 WHERE C.countMatchingProperties > n-1
```

But I did not leave a thought that this task can be solved easier and faster.

Comment: the table has two rows? or you mean two columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ObjectID 
from table 
where PropertyID in (P1, P2, P3, P4)
group by ObjectID
having count(distinct PropertyID) = 4
```

The count (e.g., `4`) must match the number of unique values in your `IN` clause.

Comment: I want hear explanation too: checked both answers and they work correct but i choose use this because it is shorter

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SD.ObjectID ObjectID,
count( SD.ObjectID )  countMatchingProperties
FROM table AS SD
WHERE SD.PropertyID IN ( P1, P2, P3, ..., Pn ) 
GROUP BY ObjectID 
having count( SD.ObjectID ) > n-1
```